# Javascript: Onclick event not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, onclick

I have tried to google this to no avail and have tried multiple options. All of which work in firefox but none have worked in IE. I have 2 onclick events on one page and neither are working in IE. The javascript file for both events is called by:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="openwindow.js"></script>
```

The first event is an anchor event which I started with as:

```
<a href="" onclick="streamwindow()">Listen Live</a>
```

then tried

```
<a href="javascript:streamwindow()">Listen Live</a>
```

then:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="streamwindow()">Listen Live</a>
```

then:

```
<a href="javascript:openwindow.js" onclick="streamwindow()">Listen Live</a>
```

then:

```
<a onclick="javascript:streamwindow()">Listen Live</a>
```

I think that is everything I have tried so far for that one. The other click event is called when the user clicks on an image. Again works fine in firefox as is but not in IE. Code for the second event is:

```
<td width="450px" align="center">
<p>Clip of The Day</p>
<img id="image2" src="images/sound.jpg" onclick="clipwindow()" />
</td>
```

I have played with this one quite as much. The javascript file (openwindow.js) contains:

```
function clipwindow()
{
window.open ('clipoftheday.html', 'Clip of the Day', 'height=200',
'width=100', 'toolbar=no', 'menubar=no', 'scrollbars=no', 'resizable=no',
'location=no', 'directories=no', 'status=no')
}

function streamwindow()
{
window.open ('stream/index.html', 'Live Stream', 'height=70', 'width=500', 'toolbar=no', 'menubar=no', 'scroolbars=no', 'resizable=no', 'location=no', 'directories=no', 'status=no')
}
```

Please help me with this. I look forward to hearing back from people.

Comment: This may not solve your problem, but popup windows can be a bad choice these days since many browsers will default to disallow that feature. for IE, try holding ctrl + click to see if that bypasses the restriction that MAY be happening. If so, I would say your best bet is to use something like colorbox to load in the files on the page itself so no user can experience this problem... Of course, if I read your situation right, it looks like an audio or video clip that you may intend to stand alone so the user can continue browsing?

Comment: You're calling "window.open()" incorrectly.  All of the window option parameters are supposed to be jammed together in a single string, separated by commas.

Comment: Pointy has a better observation. look at this link... http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Comment: ok i changed the openwindow.js but it still does not work in IE. the status bar reads error on page when i try to trigger the events

Answer (score 1):

The [`window.open()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method expects all of those height, width, etc., parameters as a single string:

```
window.open('stream/index.html', 'LiveStream',
            'height=70,width=500,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scroolbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no');
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) the window name and the string with the features should not contain blank space. I don't know why your existing code works in FF.

Most or all of your `<a>` variations should work, but of the ones you tried I'd suggest this one:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="streamwindow()">Listen Live</a>
```

Better, though, would be to set the `href` to the same URL as what the JS will open, so that the link will still work for users with JS disabled. For users with JS enabled you then return false from the `onclick` so that the default navigation doesn't occur as well as your onclick:

```
<a href="stream/index.html" onclick="streamwindow(); return false;">Listen Live</a>
```

If the above still doesn't work I'd suggest you temporarily replace the contents of your functions with a simple `alert("In function x");` message to test if the functions are being called at all.

Comment: ok, the above works in that in the IE browsers move to the correct page, however it does this even on a workstation which most defiantly has up to date java. I require the pop-up window because the window opens an audio streamer for the radio station that i work for and this would allow the users to listen whilst the continue to surf

Comment: What does Java have to do with anything? My second `<a>` syntax _will_ call your function to open a popup window while leaving the main page as it was; the point is that for users who don't have JavaScript enabled (some users turn it off in their browser) the link will still work for them. If it's not opening a popup when JavaScript is enabled there is something else wrong.

Comment: @nnnnn the thing that's wrong is, I'm pretty sure, the window name with a space in it.  IE doesn't like that.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks but I covered that in my answer (though I didn't make a big thing of it so Guy might've missed it - he does seem a bit confused about the graceful degradation stuff I mentioned).

Comment: Right - well Firefox (MDN docs notwithstanding) has never cared much about the form of window names.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. The window name (for IE) **must** be a valid identifier, so "Live Stream" won't work. Try "Live_Stream" or "LiveStream" instead.
2. The window option parameters ("scrollable", "height", etc) need to all be combined into one string, separated by commas.