# HTML onfocus, onclick events not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have what seems to be a common but mysterious problem, at least to me.  A draft of the page can be found [here](http://pages.suddenlink.net/physics/amp/amp.htm).  The desired behavior is as follows:

Perform a calculation via `<script type="text/javascript" src="amp.js"></script>` and invoke with `<body onload="amp()">`.  The details of `amp.js` are really long so I won't post those.  **Please assume that all variables are properly declared and initialized, and that all my scripts are linted.**  Next, zero-out the progress bar and counter:

```
<progress id="progress" value="100" max="100"></progress><output class="percent" id="percent">100</output><span class="prozent">%</span>
```

...when the user focuses on changing the input parameters for a new calculation:

```
<input type="number" name="theta0" id="theta0" value="0.1" min="0.0" max="1.6" step="0.1" onfocus="reset()">
```

...with `<script type="text/javascript" src="../reset.js"></script>`:

```
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true */
function reset() {
  "use strict";
  document.getElementById('progress').value = 0;
  document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = 0;
}
```

When ready, the user can perform a new calculation with `<input type="button" value="Evaluate" onclick="go = setInterval(animate, 10); amp()">` that will animate the progress bar and display the results.  The details of `<script type="text/javascript" src="../animate.js"></script>`:

```
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true */
var go = 0;
var value = 0;
var max = 100;
function animate() {
  "use strict";
  if (value >= max) {
    clearInterval(go);
    return;
  }
  var pBar,
    percent;
  pBar = document.getElementById('progress');
  percent = document.getElementById('percent');
  value += 1;
  pBar.value = value;
  percent.innerHTML = value;
  if (value === max) {
    clearInterval(go);
  }
}
```

The `onfocus` and `onclick` events don't work.  **However, calling `reset` or `animate` individually with `<body onload="">` does work.**  The console yields no clues.  A list of useful suggestions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972458/javascript-onclick-event-not-working-in-ie?rq=1).  Though I don't see the connection, I've read that sometimes bad CSS can cause weird issues.  Here's mine:

```
input {
  background-color: snow;
  border: 1px solid darkseagreen;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: indigo;
  font: 1em "Computer Modern", serif;
  width: 10%;
}
input[type=number] {
  border-left-style: none;
  border-right-style: none;
  padding-left: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
input[type=number]:focus {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-right-style: none;
  color: black;
  outline: none;
}
input[disabled] { background-color: lightgray }
```

...and...

```
input[type=button] {
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  background-image: linear-gradient(ghostwhite, #E0FFFF);
  border: 3px solid #4CC417;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: indigo;
  font: 1.1em "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
input[type=button]:hover { border: 3px solid orange }
input[type=button]:focus {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#D6F5F5, ghostwhite);
  border: 3px solid fuchsia;
  color: black;
  outline: none;
}
```

Any insights or suggestions will be appreciated.

**Update**

Interestingly, the version that is available [here](http://pages.suddenlink.net/physics/amp/amp.htm) kind of works.  `reset` is not doing its job properly, especially for additional calculations by the user.  Also, I need to add an `onchange` event to those input boxes.

Comment: Could you post a snippet? I suppose <code>go = setInterval(animate, 10); amp()</code> is not correctly parsed by JS engine.

Comment: I made a codepen of your code here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emvJpB .  The focus and hover states seem to work just fine.

Comment: Justin's codepen doesn't work for me. amp() not defined errors are raised continuously. I'm using the latest Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true */
var go = 0;
var value = 0;
var max = 100;
function animate() {
  "use strict";
  if (value >= max) {
    clearInterval(go);
    return;
  }
  var pBar,
    percent;
  pBar = document.getElementById('progress');
  percent = document.getElementById('percent');
  value += 1;
  pBar.value = value;
  percent.innerHTML = value;
  if (value === max) {
    clearInterval(go);
  }
}
```

The use/declaration of `pBar` and `percent` breaks the script.  *I have no idea why.*  Revise the script to:

```
function animate() {
  if (value >= max) {
    clearInterval(go);
    return;
  }
  value += 1;
  document.getElementById('progress').value = value;
  document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = value;
  if (value === max) {
    clearInterval(go);
  }
}
```

...and it works.  For more information, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27821961/html-progress-element-not-updating/27923546#27923546).